# Flexbox with table and absolute positioning not working in IE 10, 11 or Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

In Firefox and Chrome positioning an element to the bottom of a cell works perfectly fine.

However in IE 10, 11, Edge it appears to start the absolute position from the last piece of text in the cell. My assumption is that it has calculated the height incorrectly.

[image]

Is there a solution or workround to this issue?

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div style="flex:1">
  <table style="width:100%"><tr><td>1st line<br/>2nd line<br/>3rd line<br/>4th line<br/>5th line<br/>6th line</td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; position: relative;">1st line<br/>2st line<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 0">position bottom</div></td></tr>  
    </table></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to force the table and the cells to have a height of 100%.

This then fixed the relative issue in IE within flexbox

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div style="flex:1">
  <table style="width:100%; height: 100%"><tr><td>1st line<br/>2nd line<br/>3rd line<br/>4th line<br/>5th line<br/>6th line</td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; position: relative; height: 100%">1st line<br/>2st line<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 0">position bottom</div></td></tr>  
    </table></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should consider is that the table elements you're working with have nothing to do with flexbox. They aren't influenced by flex properties and retain their [standard CSS table properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html).

When you create a flex container (by applying `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to an element), the *child elements* become flex items. The descendants of the flex container beyond the children do not become flex items and, therefore, do not accept flex properties.

In your code, the outermost div is the flex container, making its child – the nested div – a flex item. Any descendants of this flex item are not flex-related.

Another consideration is flexbox default settings: When you create a flex container, several default rules go into effect. One of these rules is `align-items: stretch`, which tells a flex item to expand the full length of the container along the cross axis.

If you apply `display: flex` to your table row (`tr`), this converts the table cells (`td`) into flex items which automatically stretch the full height and... *your layout now works cross-browser*.

Add this to your code:

```
tr { display: flex; }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ja7p5Lc0/)

IE10 supports an older version of the flexbox spec and requires vendor prefixes. For browser compatibility data see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up when it comes to flexbox and how it does and does not effect child elements.

The issue with adding display flex is now the table row and columns' lose the default table functionality which is to scale the width of a column based on the contents inside.

I've updated the snippet to add width: 100%